# Change the text value of a button in DataGridViewButtonColumn

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I'm trying to change the text of a button in a DataGridViewButtonColumn every time the button is clicked.

I define the column like so:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn sitemapButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
{
     Name = "Process",
     Text = "Start",
     UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
     DataPropertyName = "Process",
     FillWeight = 7,
     Width = 75
};
dg_list.CellContentClick += dg_list_StartStopProcessClick;
```

Now the function which controls the event once a cell clicked is:

```
private void dg_list_StartStopProcessClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
                e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
                e.ColumnIndex == dg_lista_blogs_automatizacion.Columns["Process"].Index)
            {
                if (senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "Start")
                {
                    senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "Stop";
                    senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                }
                else
                {
                    senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "Start";
                    senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

Well, this does not work!

I've been googling and found a post which modifies UseColumnTextForButtonValue to false, set the new text value and set to true again.

The problem is that i can not figure out how can i get access to **UseColumnTextForButtonValue** property within the event.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, i could solve the problem setting **UseColumnTextForButtonValue** to false in the **DataGridViewButtonColumn** instance.

When **UseColumnTextForButtonValue** is set to false, the text value of the button must be initied in other event. So, i use **CellFormatting** event  for setting the text value according to the state I desire.

```
private void dg_list_auto_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e!=null && e.ColumnIndex==0)
            {
                dg_list_auto.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = dg_list_auto[e.RowIndex].flag_sitemap_started?"Stop":"Start";
                dg_list_auto.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = dg_list_auto[e.RowIndex].flag_sitemap_started ? Color.IndianRed: Color.GreenYellow;
            }
        }
```